# Error building iOS App (Flutter), Android runs smooth. STRIPEAPPLEPAY pod error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter, dart

I am facing this issue:

`Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): '(any PKPaymentAuthorizationControllerDelegate) -> ((PKPaymentAuthorizationController, PKShippingMethod, @escaping (PKPaymentRequestShippingMethodUpdate) -> Void) -> Void)?' is not convertible to 'pkDidSelectShippingMethodSignature' (aka 'Optional<((PKPaymentAuthorizationControllerDelegate) -> (PKPaymentAuthorizationController, PKShippingMethod, @escaping (PKPaymentRequestShippingMethodUpdate) -> ()) -> ())>') /Users/apple/Desktop/Cool%20Panda%20Apps/provider_flutter/ios/Pods/StripeApplePay/StripeApplePay/StripeApplePay/Source/ApplePayContext/STPApplePayContext.swift:239:53`

[image: Screenshot of Error Message]

Deleted PODfile.lock and Pods folder millions of times and installed pods again. Still no luck, same error.

Here is the screenshot of the PODFILE:

[image: PODFILE SCREENSHOT]

P.S: Using Xcode 14.0 (Beta) as I need to develop for iOS 16 as well.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to the latest `@stripe/stripe-react-native` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use this version in `flutter_stripe 5.1.0`
I Solve this issue `Flutter SDK version 2.10.5` & `Dart SDK 2.16`

Comment: `flutter_stripe 5.1.0` also worked with `Flutter SDK version: 3.3.9`. Thanks.